# Populate Array With Data From RecordSet

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query which holds the data I need, but I need to get the data from the query in the format of 

entity number - employee id
entity number - employee id
entity number - employee id

And so on...I tried to write my code to be the below, but I get a compile error of 
 'Compile error:
Type mismatch'
This error is thrown on the &

What is the proper way to get data from a query set-up in the format I need?  Full picture, I am wanting to get the data from the query in the XXXX - XXXX format so I can use it in the body of an email I am generating in my VBA code.

```
Dim en() As String
Dim ei() As String                                                   
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryData")
If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst
While (Not rs.EOF)
    en = en & vbCrLF & Space(7) & rs![public systems.entity number]
    ei = ei & vbCrLF & Space(7) & rs![public systems.employee id]
    rs.MoveNext
  Wend
End If
```

Comment: you are adding a recordset object to a string object.   Don't know by hart but is rs![public systems.entity number].ToString not a possibility

Comment: if I add in the .ToString - I still get the compile error on the &

Comment: You work with an Arrray, shouldn't you do ? :  en(counter) =  vbCrLF & Space(7) & rs![public systems.entity number].ToString.    counter = 0 to amount of records

Comment: Using the code you suggest above I get a debug error of Run-time error '424': Object Required on my Set rs = .... line

Comment: en(0) = vbCrLF & Space(7) & rs![public systems.entity number].ToString   If you replace en with en(0), as a start .

Comment: Still error of object required on the Set rs..... line

Comment: We are talking about VBA, right?

Comment: Yes - Access VBA

Comment: Make first your array work correctly without the recordset, using some hardcoded strings, then add the recordset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wanting to get the data from the query in the XXXX - XXXX format
>   so I can use it in the body of an email

That's not an array, so use a string:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim en As String
Dim ei As String                                                   

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryData")
If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst
    While Not rs.EOF
        en = en & vbCrLF & Space(7) & rs![public systems.entity number].Value
        ei = ei & vbCrLF & Space(7) & rs![public systems.employee id].Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End If
rs.Close
```

Comment: Using the code you suggest above I get a debug error of Run-time error '424': Object Required on my Set rs = .... line

Comment: That's not possible. I guess you missed CurrentDb.